# rc.local can't launch my program (raspbian linux)

Tags: linux, shell, daemon, startup

I have a c++ program that is running perfectly fine if I run it by executing,

```
sudo /Morreels/./launcher
```

Sadly the same line (without sudo) won't work in the rc.local file on startup...
When trying to execute rc.local on startup it gives me the following error:

> failed to start rc.local see compatibility 'systemctl-daemon'

When I try to start the rc.local service by executing :

```
service rc.local start
```

Then it gives me the following error

> Unit file of rc.local service changed on disk, 'system daemon-reload' recommended. Job for rc-local.service failed. See 'systemctl status rc-local.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details

Below (picture) I have what I get when typing : 
'systemctl status rc-local.service'

My program (launcher) relies on MySQL & A connection between arduino and ModBusMaster(485), I have been thinking that maybe these services haven't been started and thats why it fails, but I cant seem to find how to include those services into the startup list (as in msconfig for windows)

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding my `sudo /Morreels/./launcher` line to the .bashrc file in 
/home/pi folder ran everything and fixed it !